# Object's properties don't modify element's value when put into localstorage

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I have created an object which stores key-codes for DOM inputs. Initially each input is set with a default value correlated with a key-code, when updated the key-code changes, but the value of the input becomes undefined. Why is this?

```
    const inputs = localStorage.keys ? JSON.parse(localStorage.keys) : [
       {elem: document.getElementById("x1split_input"), key: null},
       {elem: document.getElementById("x2split_input"), key: 81},
       {elem: document.getElementById("x16split_input"), key: 16},
       {elem: document.getElementById("respawn_input"), key: 82}
    ]

    for(let obj of inputs){
       obj.elem.value = keyboardMap[obj.key] 
       obj.elem.onkeyup = (key) => {
           obj.key = key.keyCode
           obj.elem.value = keyboardMap[obj.key] 
           localStorage.setItem("keys", JSON.stringify(inputs))
      }
    }
    console.log(localStorage.keys) 
    //[{"elem":{},"key":null},{"elem":{"value":"Q"},"key":81},{"elem":{"value":"SHIFT"},"key":16},{"elem":{"value":"A"},"key":65}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you do retrieve your stored object from the Storage area, you have lost the Element each object's `.elem` was pointing to. All you have is a plain Object, and adding an `onkeyup` method on these won't do the same as if they were the actual elements.

```js
const inputs = [ { elem: document.getElementById("my-input") } ];
console.log( inputs ); // [ { "elem": <input id="my-input"> } ]

const in_storage = JSON.stringify( inputs );
console.log( in_storage ); // '[{"elem":{}}]'

const from_storage = JSON.parse( in_storage );
console.log( from_storage ); // [ { "elem": {} } ]
```

```html
<input id="my-input">
```

So you actually need to retrieve the elements from the document every time you'll retrieve your objects from the StorageArea.

To do so, you can use both the reviver function that you can pass to [*JSON.parse( string, reviver )*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and the *replacer* one you can pass to [*JSON.stringify( object, replacer )*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) so that instead of saving empty objects, you save only your Element's `id` at stringification, and instead of retrieving only this string, you get directly the Element at parsing.

```js
// used in JSON.parse
function reviver( key, value ) {
  if( key === "elem" ) {
    return document.getElementById( value );
  }
  return value;
}
// used in JSON.stringify
function replacer( key, value ) {
  if( key === "elem" ) {
    return value.id;
  }
  return value
}

// StackSnippets don't allow localStorage
// so let's make a fake one, already populated
const localStorage = {
  keys: `[
    {"elem":"x1split_input","key":null},
    {"elem":"x2split_input","key":81},
    {"elem":"x16split_input","key":16},
    {"elem":"respawn_input","key":82}
  ]`,
  setItem(key, val) {
    this[key] = val;
    console.log( 'saving', val );
  }
};
const keyboardMap = {81:'foo', 16:'bar', 82:'bla'};

btn.onclick = e => {
const inputs = localStorage.keys ? JSON.parse(localStorage.keys, reviver) : [
  // your initial object, not used in this demo
]

for (let obj of inputs) {
  obj.elem.value = keyboardMap[obj.key];
  obj.elem.onkeyup = (key) => {
    obj.key = key.keyCode;
    obj.elem.value = keyboardMap[obj.key];
    localStorage.setItem("keys", JSON.stringify(inputs, replacer))
  }
}
console.log(localStorage.keys)

}
```

```html
<button id="btn">retrieve from (fake) localStorage</button><br>
<input id="x1split_input"><br>
<input id="x2split_input"><br>
<input id="x16split_input"><br>
<input id="respawn_input"><br>
```